# Is pointer arithmetic still well defined after casting with alignment violation?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, memory-alignment, c11, pointer-arithmetic

I know that the result of pointer casting with alignment violation invokes undefined behaviour once dereferenced.

But what about pointer casting for address calculation only (without dereferencing)?

```
void *addr_calc(single_byte_aligned_struct_t *ptr, uint32_t dword_offset)
{
    uint32_t *dw_ptr = (uint32_t *)ptr;

    return dw_ptr + dword_offset;
}
```

Let's assume the value of `ptr` is *X*. Is it guaranteed that that `addr_calc()` will return `X + sizeof(uint32_t) * dword_offset`?

My assumption was that it is but recently I saw the following in the C11 standard, section *J.2 Undefined behaviour*

> — Conversion between two pointer types produces a result that is incorrectly aligned (6.3.2.3).

If I understood it correctly, the casting itself invokes undefined behaviour, not only dereferencing, which means that even the pointer arithmetic may behave unpredictably in such case. Am I right?

Comment: The main problem here, not addressed by any of the current answers, is that the + operator doesn't have a well-defined behavior in case the pointer operands don't point at the same array (where plain variables are treated as an array with size 1). See [Is it undefined behaviour to just make a pointer point outside boundaries of an array without dereferencing it?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277215), it's the same issue.

Comment: @Lundin I am not sure it is the same thing. My question is more about the line ‘uint32_t dw_ptr = (uint32_t *)ptr;’. Let’s assume that ‘+ dw_offset’ doest cause out of array bounds result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can in fact result in undefined behavior if `ptr` is not properly aligned for `uint32_t`.  Some systems might allow it but others could trigger a fault.

A safe conversion would be to `char *`, then doing the pointer arithmetic on that.

```
return (char *)ptr + dword_offset * sizeof(uint32_t);
```

Comment: Probably converting to `uintptr_t` and performing the address calculation would also be OK, right?

Comment: @AlexLop. That would work as well, but then you'd need another explicit cast back to a pointer type.  Converting any pointer type to a `void *` doesn't require a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understood it correctly. As an example, on some computers that are word-addressed but nevertheless have a `char` type that is smaller than the word, an `int *` pointer could be of *smaller size*, so there is no telling what casting an unaligned `char *` to `int *` would do - but a trap would be a *best-case* scenario.

If you need byte-wise pointer arithmetic, use a pointer to a character type. *All* other object pointer types should **ever** be used only for referencing *true objects* or *arrays* of the pointed-to type.

Answer (score 0):

A notable example of a situation where casting an unaligned pointer may result in a malfunction would be when processing:

```
void test(void *dest, void *src)
{
    uint32_t *d = dest;
    uint32_t *s = src;
    memcpy(d, s, 4);
}
```

with clang on a platform that doesn't support unaligned word accesses.  In cases where the source and destination do not overlap, the behavior of `memcpy(d, s, 4);` is specified as being equivalent to:

```
((unsigned char*)d)[0] = ((unsigned char*)s)[0];
((unsigned char*)d)[1] = ((unsigned char*)s)[1];
((unsigned char*)d)[2] = ((unsigned char*)s)[2];
((unsigned char*)d)[3] = ((unsigned char*)s)[3];
```

Clang, however, will exploit the fact that a `uint32_t*` can be presumed never to hold an unaligned address, and thus generate code which uses a single 32-bit load and store, and will thus only work if the pointers are aligned.  Although the code clang generates to perform the assignment to a `uint32_t*` wouldn't care about whether the pointer is aligned, and although the pointer is coerced to `void*` when it is passed to `memcpy`, the conversion of the pointer to `uint32_t*` within that sequence of events will cause clang to generate code that *does* care about alignment.

Comment: This is true one can say that it happens because of the pointer dereferencing. You actually (access) get data from `s` and copy (access) it to `d`. My question was specifically about casting for address calculation, without further access to the calculated address.

Comment: @AlexLop.: The `memcpy` function is specified as behaving as though it copies individual bytes, without any requirement that the source and/or destination address be aligned.  Semantically, the code is equivalent to converting the passed address to `uint32_t*`, then having `memcpy` convert it to `uint8_t*` and use that to perform the accesses.